# The gun lies/sits between them on the floor

Tags: word-choice

The two men have crashed down the stairs to the basement. The gun lies/sits between them on the floor.

Are both 'lies' and 'sits' OK here?

Comment: I prefer using sit/stand to describe objects which are upright like a stand, bike, bookshelf. Anything else which is flat in a horizontal position, I use lie.

Answer (score 1):

Both give a similar impression, but I prefer "lie" since the gun will tend to be flat on the ground, rather like a person who is lying down.

Answer (score 1):

Both possible. Both idiomatic.
Literally, a gun is more likely to *lie* (on its side) on the ground. Somewhat passively.
Stylistically, if it *sits* between two people, it is 'sitting up' and ready for action. Something might be about to happen.

Where might a gun naturally *sit*? On a shelf, on a cushion, in your hand, in your pocket.